# Bit width different in verilog

Tags: verilog, fpga, asic

What is different between `{a + b}` and `(a + b)` in verilog. I used the simulation to do:

```
reg [3:0] a = 4'b0001;
reg [3:0] b = 4'b1111;
reg [4:0] c = (a + b); give the result c = 5'b1_0000
```

but

```
reg [4:0] c = {a + b}; give c = 5'b0_0000;
```

It means the (a + b) can give the result 5 bits, but {a + b} give 4 bits. I don't know why. Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: I think the question is why is the output different if the concatenation operator is used.  This is by no means an answer, but I think that the fact that a and b are both 4 bits wide is part of the issue relative to the concat operator being used.  It might be worth while to prove that letting a and b become 5 bits wide get the expected behavior.  At that point I think it comes down to how the concatenation operator slices the result width.

Comment: I don't know but with the concatenation the result will be 4 bits, I used this to assign to the 4 bit signal.

Comment: IEEE Std 1364-2005 5.4 Expression bit lengths, IEEE Std 1800-2012 11.6 Expression bit lengths. (a+b) is a context determined bit length  while {a+b} is a self determined bit length using the max(L(a), L(b).

Answer (score 3):

Each expression in a concatenation is self-determined. `{expr1,expr2, ...}`. In your example, there is just one expression, and it happens to be `a + b`. According to Section *11.6 Expression bit lengths* in the IEEE 1800-2012 LRM , L(a+b) in a self-determined context is Max(L(a),L(b)), which is 4 bits. Otherwise it is 5 bits in a context of an assignment.